# XSD SimpleType that requires empty or 2 chars

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I am trying to figure out how to change XSD that require node "Initials" which is empty or 2 chars only.

```
 <xs:simpleType name="Initials">
    <xsd:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:maxLength value="2"/>
      <xs:minLength value="2"/>
      <xs:pattern value="[A-Z]+"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

Should I do it as nillable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the pattern value `([A-Z][A-Z])?`.

Answer (score 1):

With a sample XML like

```
<root>AZ</root>
```

or

```
<root></root>
```

your XSD could look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="root" type="Initials" />

  <xs:simpleType name="Initials">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="|[A-Z]{2}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

Its `xs:pattern` does match a zero length string or a two character A-Z string. Removing the `<xs:maxLength value="2"/>` and the `<xs:minLength value="2"/>` was necessary to take care of the zero length string.